# Support Multi-Language in MFC project without using dll

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have created different .rc files for e.g Japanese.rc and English.rc. I want to load their respective strings on the basis of user  not on the basis of locale system language.

I tried the following approach:

```cpp
// Assume the languagePreference is set by the user (e.g., through a settings menu)
    
CString resourcePath = L"C:\\Users\\Meritech-43\\source\\repos\\MFCAppMulti-Language\\MFCAppMulti-Language";

CString languagePreference = L"Japanese"; // or "English"

// Construct the resource file name based on the user's language preference
CString resourceFileName = (languagePreference.CompareNoCase(L"Japanese") == 0) ? resourcePath + L"\\Japanese.rc" : resourcePath + L"\\MFCAppMultiLanguage.rc";
// TRACE(_T("My variable value: %d\n"), resourceFileName);
// Load the resource file dynamically
HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(resourceFileName);
if (hModule != nullptr) {
    // Successfully loaded resources, set the resource handle
    AfxSetResourceHandle(hModule);

    // Load the strings dynamically
    CString strTitle, strHelloMessage;
    strTitle.LoadString(IDS_APP_TITLE);
    strHelloMessage.LoadString(IDS_HELLO_MESSAGE);

    // Display or use the loaded strings as needed
    AfxMessageBox(strTitle + L"\n" + strHelloMessage);

    // Unload the current resource handle
    AfxSetResourceHandle(nullptr);
}
else {
    // Failed to load resources, handle the error
    AfxMessageBox(L"Failed to load resources for the selected language.");
}
```

But every time `LoadLibrary(resourceFileName)?` returns a `null` value. `CString resourceFileName` contains the respective .rc file name with full path.

Comment: Inspect `GetLastError()`, perhaps it clues you in on what happened.

Comment: Please read the Win32 documentation. `LoadLibrary()` loads a DLL, while a resource file in meant to be compiled with the resource compiler and linked into an executable (.exe or .dll).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that I've used in the past to acheive this:

This presumes, that you've compiled all your resource files into the main exe.

```
wchar_t* GetStringFromStringTable(UINT lang, UINT subLang, UINT uStringID)
{

    wchar_t* pwchMem, * pwchCur;
    UINT      idRsrcBlk = uStringID / 16 + 1;
    int       strIndex = uStringID % 16;
    HINSTANCE hModule = NULL;
    HRSRC     hResource = NULL;

    hResource = FindResourceEx(nullptr, RT_STRING,
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(idRsrcBlk),
        MAKELANGID(lang, subLang));

    if (hResource != NULL)
    {
        pwchMem = (wchar_t*)LoadResource(hModule, hResource);

        if (pwchMem != NULL)
        {
            pwchCur = pwchMem;
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                if (*pwchCur)
                {
                    int cchString = *pwchCur;  // String size in characters.
                    pwchCur++;
                    if (i == strIndex)
                    {
                        // The string has been found in the string table.
                        wchar_t* pwchTemp = new wchar_t[cchString];
                        wcsncpy(pwchTemp, pwchCur, cchString);
                        pwchTemp[cchString] = '\0';

                        return pwchTemp;
                    }
                    pwchCur += cchString;
                }
                else
                    pwchCur++;
                }
            }
        }
    return NULL;

}
```

You can then call it like so:

```
WCHAR* english = GetStringFromStringTable(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT, IDS_HELLO_MESSAGE);
WCHAR* spanish = GetStringFromStringTable(LANG_SPANISH, SUBLANG_SPANISH_ARGENTINA, IDS_HELLO_MESSAGE);
```

The LANG_* and SUBLANG_* values to use can be found in yout respective .rc for each of your languages you have defined (with the exception of US english, when you should use `LANG_NEUTRAL`, `SUBLANG_DEFAULT`)